# Cannot create a cronJob for every minute from templates openshift

Tags: cron, openshift

When I give input for schedule parameter * * * * * the oc export fails with invalid character.

Error: YAML parse error on middleware/templates/cyes-rest/timed-out-streams-cron-job.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 12: did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character

```
  timedOutStreamsCronJob:
    enabled: true
    schedule: '* * * * *'
```

timed-out-streams-cron-job.yaml

```
{{- if and .Values.cyes.enabled .Values.cyes.timedOutStreamsCronJob.enabled -}}
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ include "middleware.fullname" . }}-timed-out-streams-cron-job
  labels:
    {{- include "middleware.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  schedule: {{.Values.cyes.timedOutStreamsCronJob.schedule}}
  jobTemplate: 
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: sync-cron
            image: {{.Values.cyes.timedOutStreamsCronJob.image.repository}}:{{.Values.cyes.timedOutStreamsCronJob.image.tag}}
            args:
            - wget
            - -O-
            - http://{{ .Release.Name }}-{{.Values.cyes.name}}-service:{{.Values.cyes.port}}/checkStreams
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
      startingDeadlineSeconds: 3600
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: Please add your YAML file content (timed-out-streams-cron-job.yaml) to your post so we can review the content of the file.

Comment: @Simon I added as you requested

Answer (score 1):

I believe we are looking at a formatting issue regarding the quotes, as CronJobs should look like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"  
[..]
```

So your spec should likely look like this (note the "):

```
spec:
  schedule: "{{.Values.cyes.timedOutStreamsCronJob.schedule}}"
```